# Do I need a semicolon after a named export function declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

First, this is NOT a question about ASI. I'm not asking whether or not automatic semicolon insertion applies here (well, I kind of am, but that opening statement is an attempt at avoiding arguments between whether I should or shouldn't use a semicolon because asi will take care of it for me...)

I know not to put a semicolon after a function declaration...

```
function foo() { 
  // do stuff
} // no semicolon
```

But do I need a semicolon after `export`ing a function declaration?

```
export function foo() {
  // do stuff
} // semicolon or not to semicolon?
```

In either case, I would also love to know why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you do not need a semi-colon, though adding one will do no harm.

If we look at [the ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports), you will see that this signature is considered a *declaration* and, like normal function declarations, does not need a semicolon after it:

> `export Declaration`

The statements that need to be followed by a semi-colon (whether explicit or implicit) are noted as such in that document. For example:

> `export *` *FromClause* **`;`**

There the `;` is mandatory. In the declaration, it is not. Of course, inserting the semicolon will not do any harm; the JS interpreter will treat it as an empty statement.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need a semicolon here. See this example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export):

> ```
> export default function() {} // or 'export default class {}'
> // there is no semi-colon here
> ```

See also [the ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-exports):

> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> ExportDeclaration :
>   export * FromClause ;
>   export ExportClause[~Local] FromClause ;
>   export ExportClause[+Local] ;
>   export VariableStatement[~Yield, ~Await]
>   export Declaration[~Yield, ~Await]
>   export defaultHoistableDeclaration[~Yield, ~Await, +Default]
>   export defaultClassDeclaration[~Yield, ~Await, +Default]
>   export default[lookahead ∉ { function, async [no LineTerminator here] function, class }]AssignmentExpression[+In, ~Yield, ~Await] ;
> ```

As you see, there's no semicolon after `Declaration`.

Comment: yeah, but that's a `default export` i'm wondering specifically about `named exports`

Comment: @sfletche Why would it be different with named exports?

Comment: i don't know whether is would or wouldn't.  (which is one reason i'm asking the question)